# How to force djCurrencyTextBox to show currency symbol in read mode?

Tags: dojo, xpages, dijit.form, dijit.layout

It is shown when the document is in edit mode. Setting constraints symbol="$" doesn't help.

```
<xe:djCurrencyTextBox id="budget" value="#{document1.budget}" defaultValue="0">
    <xe:this.constraints>
        <xe:djNumberConstraints
            currency="USD" type="currency" fractional="false">
        </xe:djNumberConstraints>
    </xe:this.constraints>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber></xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xe:djCurrencyTextBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameter `showReadonlyAsDisabled="true"` to your djCurrencyTextBox control:

```
<xe:djCurrencyTextBox
    id="budget"
    value="#{document1.budget}"
    defaultValue="0"
    showReadonlyAsDisabled="true">
```

[image]

It will show your currency value with "$" symbol in read mode.

Comment: Thank you. It works but now I adds a border. But I can solve it with CSS